# check if string contains same characters twice

Tags: c#, string

How can I check if the string contains the same words twice?

Something like:

- `" <Item> MyString <Item> <Item> MyString <Item> "` → `true`
- `" <Item> MyString <Item> <Item> NotMyString <Item> "` → `false`
- `" <Item> MyString <Item> <Fact> MyString <Fact> "` → `false`

I only get the original string at run-time, and it isn't necessarily the first batch of words in the string.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: What about `"My String My String"` and `"  "` and `"MyString MyString abcd"`?

Comment: `MyString NotMyString` contains the same *characters* twice - it just doesn't contain the same *words* twice. You need to be more precise in your requirements.

Comment: I don't understand the spec: `MyString MyString` - true and `MyString MyString` - false What's the difference between those two?

Comment: There's a slight difference between `characters` and `words`. Furthermore, it seems even you can't decide how to calculate the result, as Matthew already pointed out. You show 2 exact examples with 2 different results. This is a very badly explained problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for any word to be used twice, use the `Split` function to make a string into words, and then `Group` to get counts:

```
string input = "MyString MyString";
var words = input.Split().GroupBy(s => s).ToDictionary(
                                                  g => g.Key, 
                                                  g => g.Count()
                                          );
```

The dictionary `words` will be a set of `key` and `value` pairs where the key is the word, and the value is the number of times its in your input string. If you want to find words which occur more than once:

```
bool hasDuplicateWords = words.Any(w => w.Value > 1);
```

To find which words occur multiple times:

```
var duplicateWords = words.Where(w => w.Value > 1);
```

---

Edit: After editting your question, it seems you are not parsing simple strings, but parsing XML code. You should use an XML parser to work with XML, something like this (not checked in editor):

```
var input = "<Item> MyString <Item> <Item> MyString <Item>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(input);

bool hasDuplicateWords = xml.Children
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                            .Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: your input is not a valid xml

Comment: Probably should contain a root tag and close tags.... but didnt want to edit original poster's supplied value.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `string.Split()` which would split the string based on the spaces and then you can check th count for the string to compare and see if it is equal to or greater than `2`

```
string strToCompare = "MyString";
string str = " MyString MyString ";

if(str.Split().Count(r=> r == strToCompare) >= 2)
   //exists twice or more
```

**EDIT:** Since the question has now been edited. You can try the following:

```
var duplicateArray = str.Split()
                        .GroupBy(r=> r) 
                        .Where(t=> t.Count() >= 2)
                        .ToArray();
```

Tha above would give you arrays of those words whose count in the string is twice or more.

Comment: Neat solution - but wouldn't it fail for strings like "MyStringMyString" or "MyString adbadMyString"?

Comment: @Tim, I believe he is searching for word, --

Comment: Question is not to search for an input string, it is to search for duplicate words.

Comment: @WillemDuncan, the original question was not clear enough to know about the exact requirement. I haved modified my answer according to current edit of the question

Comment: @WillemDuncan, its again edited :)

Comment: I went to add code blocks to this question to make it readable and found XML tags in his strings that didnt render in the browser. Caught me by suprise as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = " MyString MyString ";

var result = str.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .GroupBy(word => word)
                .Any(grp => grp.Count() > 1);

Console.WriteLine (result); // will print true
```