# Is it possible to simplify this Linq Query Syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a sequence of words with some repeated, such as this:

```
var words = "one two three two four five six four seven four eight".Split(' ');
```

<strike>You can find duplicates like this</strike> You can group the words like this:

```
var g1 = words.GroupBy(w => w);
```

I was trying to rewrite that into Linq Query sytnax, just to see what it looks like (I'm aware that in real code you would just leave it like the line above!).

The Linq I came up with looks far more complicated than it should, I think. How can it be simplified? And is it *really* the same as the line above?

```
var g2 = from w in words group w by w into g select g;
```

(I think I'm having a Sunday Brain-Fade... ;)

[EDIT] My source for this wonderment was from the answers to [this question from earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997212/check-if-string-contains-same-characters-twice#comment22810301_15997212).

Comment: Sorry I meant how to simplify the query syntax. Have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the above are LINQ versions. One is method expression and the other is [Query Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx). There is no difference between them.

You should see: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx)

If you mean to simplyfy Query syntax then I don't think you can modify it too much, since its equvivalent to your method syntax.

Comment: I mean to ask how to simplify the query syntax. You are saying that's simplest version, then?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, yes they are equivalent .

Comment: Thanks, I've previously read the documentation you linked; I was just wondering why it seemed so hard to simplify the Linq Query syntax - now I know why; you can't!

Answer (score 5):

**Your query does not return duplicates**, it returns distinct items, so you could easily use  `Distinct()` extension method.

```
var dist = words.Distinct();
```

`Distinct()` has no equivalent in syntax queries.

If you really look for duplicates you have to change your query to:

```
var g1 = words.GroupBy(w => w).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

and in syntax query

```
var g1 = from w in words
         group w by w into g
         where g.Count() > 1
         select g.Key;
```

However, the second one will be translated into the first one by compiler.

I don't see any easier way to get this using syntax query.

Comment: Thanks, but the intended usage was perhaps a bit misleading. I just wanted to know if there was a way to simplify the Linq query that I posted. I'm not really using it for anything. I've linked in my question the SO answer that got me to thinking about this.